# How to quickly create difference sizes of images for a Xamarin Forms project?

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, size

I just started learning Xamarin Forms. I noticed in some open source projects there are images named like `logo.png`, `logo@2x.png` and `logo@4x.png`. Normally how does these images were created?

Comment: Is this a question about computer programming? (Please add extra detail to explain how - questions about using a batch image resizer to quickly provide different sizes of N images is more a superuser question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout Resizetizer NT which will size icons automatically for you.

1. Install [the NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Resizetizer.NT/0.1.0-preview7)
2. Add your images (PNG or SVG) to your shared project as type `SharedImage`
3. Set a base size within your shared project's csproj file for each image (see below)

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <SharedImage Include="xamagon.svg" BaseSize="60,60" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Checkout [the link](https://redth.codes/resizetizer-nt-shared-images-for-xamarin/) for more detailed steps.